# Books on set and proof theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, set-theory, book-recommendation

I have recently been fascinated by theorems and statements in set and proof theory, such as formally demonstrating the independence of propositions (eg, independence of the Continuum Hypothesis from ZFC, independence of AC from standard ZF axioms, etc) and am interested in self-studying these problems in greater depth. I am looking for a book or other source I could learn from, which focuses on nontrivial applications of foundational set theory to problems like those I described above. I am a first year CS undergrad, but have some mathematical maturity and self study experience (I am currently working through Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra). I would prefer if the book focused more on problems and applications (to problems in set theory, of course) rather than developing the theory as fast as possible

Comment: “Introduction to Set Theory” by Thomas Jech is a good place to start for a formal introduction to set theory. Jech also has a book called “Set Theory” but this is more advanced

Comment: What you suggested in your question is less related to proof theory and closer to set theory, so you should find textbooks on set theory, but there is not much choice beyond some level.

Comment: In a somewhat different vein, you might try the works of Raymond Smullyan. I liked Satan, Cantor and Infinity, and the Godelian Puzzle Book, which deals with some of these issues in a light-hearted but insightful way.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is great for a first year undergrad, but Don Monk's "Notes on Set Theory" is a solid text.

Comment: Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs, by Kenneth Kunen.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet that book looks interesting, is it suitable for a newcomer to the subject?

Comment: Kunen is self-contained and detailed. I think a beginner could handle it slowly, with careful re-reading. There are many exercises & problems. You can skip the chapter Defining Definability at first.